# How can I improve this code jquery search code?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code here. It works pretty well but locks up if I type too fast. I love to see how i can improve it. It will search through a MySql table and return results based on criteria from many columns.

```
<script src="jquery-v2.0.3.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search_results").slideUp(); 
    $("#search_button").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        ajax_search(); 
    }); 

    $("#search_term").keyup(function(e){ 
        delay(function(){
         //alert('Time elapsed!');
        }, 1000 );
        e.preventDefault(); 
        ajax_search(); 
    }); 

}); 

function ajax_search(){
    $("#search_results").show(); 
    var search_val=$("#search_term").val(); 
    $.post("findcourses.php", {search_term : search_val}, function(data) {
        if (data.length>0){ 
            $("#search_results").html(data); 
        } 
    }) 
}
```

Comment: indent your code. How can you even believe we will read that ?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

Answer (score -1):

Couple of things I see -

First, `e.preventDefault()` doesn't do anything in a keyup event.  Whatever you are expecting that to do isn't working, it works on a keydown event though.

Then right here:

```
$("#search_term").keyup(function(e){ 
    delay(function(){
     //alert('Time elapsed!');
    }, 1000 );
    e.preventDefault(); 
    ajax_search(); 
});
```

You are calling the delay function, and then immediately calling `ajax_search()`.  The search is after the delay function, but it doesn't wait.  `ajax_search()` needs to be in your callback

```
$("#search_term").keyup(function(e){ 
    delay(function(){
      ajax_search();
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track with your delay, but it should be implemented differently. Now, it wait a second after the keyup trigger, then runs the ajax call - it still calls ajax per keystroke, eventually. This is likely the main drag. *(pointed out by Jeff in another answer;  it actually doesn't wait the second at all because the ajax function call is outside of the delay function)*

Instead, don't bother with the delay (unless it has a different functionality) and instead do a simple if_in_ajax boolean check. For example -

```
var if_in_ajax = false,
    do_ajax_anyways = false;
function ajax_search(){
  $("#search_results").show(); 
  var search_val=$("#search_term").val(); 

  if ( !if_in_ajax || do_ajax_anyways ) {
    $.post("findcourses.php", {search_term : search_val}, function(data) {
      // Now ajax call is running
      if_in_ajax = true;

      if (data.length>0){ 
        $("#search_results").html(data); 
      } 
    })
    .always(function() {
      // After the post call is finished, we're done in ajax
      if_in_ajax = do_ajax_anyways = false;
    });
  }

}
```

---

If you can reasonably ensure the ajax call will only take one second, feel free to leave the delay. With the additional check above you should avoid most lag issues.

```
$("#search_term").keyup(function(e){ 
    delay(function(){
       ajax_search(); 
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Possibly better, call the ajax search on blur as well (i.e. when they leave the input). Perhaps add a search icon next to the input the hint they need to click off of the box in order to search.

```
$("#search_term").blur(function(e){
    do_ajax_anyways = true;
    ajax_search(); 
});
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is if i were to type "Hello" into the text field, it would send an ajax request for 'H', and then ignore the rest of my keyups because the ajax request for 'H' hasn't returned yet, but the results i want are for 'Hello', not 'H'.

Comment: @KevinB That's true, see my update. The function is still sent per keyup, but yeah if it doesn't reurn fast enough the rest wont call, even with the delay. Likely the best solution is to call ajax agan on the blur event. Perhaps force the call on blur